# Initializing the forget gate in LSTM network using Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, lstm

I have read that regulating the bias term is important to improve the performance of LSTM networks. Here are some sources:

https://www.exxactcorp.com/blog/Deep-Learning/5-types-of-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-and-what-to-do-with-them

http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/jozefowicz15.pdf

Does anyone know how to actually implement this in Pytorch?

Comment: Kindly phrase your question properly with copy-pasting relevant parts of these documents. Please do not just put links in questions.

Comment: Check out the variables section in the official [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) and relevant [question](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/set-forget-gate-bias-of-lstm/1745/4) on pytorch forum. They will show you to access and modify the specific weights of LSTM layer